# Search number list in multiple files and print

Tags: grep, cat

I am trying to find a few numbers listed in a file and their next +16 rows, from a bunch of files in a folder.

Print or store output in a file, but the command is not displaying any output

```
for i in `cat /home/gemapp/My_data/File_08_09.txt`; do grep -A 16 '$i' *MP.X* ;done
```

Answer (score 0):

The single quotes around `'$i'` make it literal; if you want `$i` to be ecxpanded by the shell you should use double quotes`"$i"`.

However it would be better to use grep's `-f` option to read patterns from your text file in a single invocation. Assuming your file contains one string to be matched per line, and that they should be matched as fixed strings not regular expressions (`-F`), that would be something like

```
grep -A 16 -F -f /home/gemapp/My_data/File_08_09.txt *MP.X*
```